# submit button issue with jquery and php

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem:

when the input type on my submit button is changed to 'button' it does NOT save info to mysql but validation works. If i change it to input type on submit button to 'submit' it saves info to mysql but the validation does not work. Is there a resolution to this?

jquery validation - function on click:

```
 $("input:button").click(function(){         
               var retVal = false;
               $.each([1, 2], function(i, val){
                  retVal = (validate(val) || retVal);
               });
                return retVal;
```

On my form the submit button code is:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The form action is:

```
   <form name="list1"; action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `$("input:submit")` instead `$("input:button")` in your jQuery code

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this is to the leave the button as `<input type='submit' />` and use `$('form').submit(...)` to return `true/false` based on the validation.